# Wann benutzt man Genitiv + reflexives Verb

Tags: grammatical-case

Ich habe eine Genitivform der reflexiven Pronomen in einer Grammatiktabelle gesehen, und zwar: mich (akk), mir (dat) und meiner (gen). Aber wann verwendet man eigentlich die letzte Form in Kontext von Reflexivverben?

Comment: Bist du sicher in Genitivform? Reflexive Verbe sind ganz ähnlich zu akkusativ Personalpromonmen, nur in drittem Person wird "sich" verwendet! Aber das nicht Genitiv, sonst fast Akkusativ.

Comment: Hier in diesem Link zum Beispiel: https://online-lernen.levrai.de/deutsch-uebungen/grammatik_5_7/27_pronomen/reflexivpronomen.htm steht es so.

Comment: Uhm, richtig. Nach meiner Meinung sind diese nicht Reflexivpronome, aber die Sprachlehrer haben ein Slang, das ich respektiere als [argumentum ad verecundiam](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_verecundiam).

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt ohnehin nur sehr wenige Verben, die mit dem Genitiv stehen, die Zahl der reflexiven Verben mit Genitiv kann man an zwei Händen abzählen und die Verben aus dieser Gruppe, bei denen das Personalpronomen im Genitiv verwendet werden kann, sind

> Morpheus bemächtigte sich meiner.
>
> Die Armee bediente sich meiner.
>
> Als es darum ging, einen Dummkopf zu finden, entsann man sich meiner.
>
> Später erinnerte sich niemand meiner.
>
> Meine Leute schämten sich meiner.

Diese Ausdrücke sind alle sehr ungewöhnlich. Man wird sie in Gedichten finden, oder als spezielle Stilmittel in Erzählungen. Daher auch die gestelzten Beispiele.

---

EDIT: Da die Frage wohl anders gemeint war, hier noch Beispiele für die Verwendung von *meiner* mit nicht-reflexiven Verben, die den Genitiv führen:

> Man bedurfte meiner.
>
> Sie gedachten meiner.

Auch diese Liste ist sehr kurz, und auch diese Ausdrücke sind sehr ungewöhlich und gestelzt.

Comment: Diese Beispiele benötigt noch eine 'sich' (der reflexiver pronomen) neben die  'meiner', oder? Das Wort 'sich' ist immer noch nicht wegzulassen und deshalb 'meiner' hier funktioniert nicht als die reflexive Pronomen

Comment: @ZhanfengLim: Richtig wäre: *»Diese Beispiele benötigen noch ein 'sich' (ein reflexives Pronomen) neben 'meiner', oder? Das Wort 'sich' kann immer noch nicht weggelassen werden und deshalb funktioniert hier 'meiner' nicht als reflexives Pronomen.«*

Comment: @Zhanfeng Lim: Es gibt im Deutschen nur ein einziges Reflexivpronomen: *sich*. Bei den anderen Pronomen kann man deren reflexive oder nicht-reflexive Bedeutung nur anhand der Logik des Satzes erkennen.

Comment: Ich habe meine Antwort ergänzt.

Answer (score 1):

Grundsätzlich haben reflexive Verben im Deutschen kein besonderes Unterscheidungsmerkmal: Es sind einfach Verben, in denen ein Objekt – ob zufällig oder systematisch – mit dem Subjekt übereinstimmt. Viele Verben existieren »sowohl in einer transitiven Form als auch in einer reflexiven Form« (Anführungszeichen, da man das gesagte nicht zu genau nehmen sollte). Zum Beispiel gibt es *jemanden sehen* (mit Akkusativobjekt) aber auch *sich sehen* (reflexiv), die sich eigentlich nur darin unterscheiden, wer gesehen wird.

Die fließende Übergang wird besonders in den ersten beiden Personen klar: wo in der dritten Person das dezidierte Reflexivpronomen *sich* steht, heißt es *mir/mich, dir/dich, uns, euch* – exakt diejenigen Formen eines normalen Objekts.

Einige wenige Verben im Deutschen verlangen ein Genitivobjekt. Das, welches einem vielleicht am häufigsten einfällt, ist *jemandes gedenken*. Semantisch kräuseln sich mir zwar alle Fingernägel, aber grammatikalisch ist nichts gegen einen solchen Beispielsatz einzuwenden:

> Er gedachte seiner.

Oder in der ersten Person:

> Ich gedachte meiner.

(Die dritte Person krankt ein wenig daran, dass *seiner* auch das übliche Genitivobjekt der dritten Person, singular, maskulin ist.)

Comment: Zum letzten Satz: Deswegen packt man gemeinhin ein "selbst" hinter das Pronomen, um deutlich zu machen, was man meint: "Er gedachte seiner selbst"

Answer (score 1):

Ein Reflexivpronomen gibt es nur in der dritten Person, denn nur dort findet man einen Kontrast zwischen Reflexiv- und Personalpronomen.

> Er sieht **ihn** im Spiegel. *(zwei verschiedene Personen)*
>   **Er** sieht **sich** im Spiegel. *(ein- und dieselbe Person)*

Das Erstaunliche am Reflexivpronomen ist, daß es sowohl Akkusativ als auch Dativ sein kann, während diese Kasus im gesamten Singular und in der 3. Plural der Personalpronomen unterschieden werden (*mich, mir; dich, dir; sie, ihr; es/ihn, ihm; sie, ihnen*).

> **Ich** bin **mir** sicher und **er** ist **sich** sicher.
>   **Er** ist mit **sich** im Reinen.

Wenn man von einem Reflexivpronomen nur dann sprechen kann, wenn es sich vom Personalpronomen unterscheidet, gibt es kein Reflexivpronomen im Genitiv, denn *sich* kann nicht stehen, wo ein Genitiv gefordert ist, und *seiner* ist der Genitiv des Personalpronomens.

Aber es gibt natürlich Fälle, in denen *seiner* sich auf das Subjekt bezieht, wie das begleitende *selbst* anzeigt bzw. sicherstellt.

> **Er** war **seiner** selbst überdrüssig und ergab sich dem Trunk.
>   **Nietzsche** ist auch ein Kritiker **seiner** selbst.